# How do I programmatically access the Document Well in Visual Studio..?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-sdk

I would like to write a simple Visual Studio Add-In for managing tabs in the Document Well. There are many such add-ins already available, such as Tabs Studio, Tidy Tabs, Visual Docs, etc, but I would like to try it myself.

Where can I find documentation on programming the Document Well..???

I've searched extensively for days with Google, and in the help files for VS and VSSDK, but I cannot find *any* documentation on how to access the Document Well. I've also examined the various project templates under Visual Basic Extensibility and C# Extensibility that were added by VSSDK, but none of these seem to have anything related to the document well.

I even jumped into the deep end, and created a blank project and added references to *all* the DLL files that were installed by VSSDK, and then searched the Object Explorer for every related word or term I could think of, but still I could not find any namespaces, collections, or other objects that seem to have anything to do with the document well. I seem to be completely missing or misunderstanding something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no public MS API to access the Document Well. If you just want to manage open windows and documents, you can use DTE.Windows and DTE.Documents collections.

(My Tabs Studio add-in creates a completely new tabs control and then fully replaces the built-in tabs well.)

Comment: Ahhh well that explains it then. I've been looking for something that isn't there. The VSSDK documentation makes it sound like all components of the IDE GUI are accessible via DTE for manipulation, but it seems that's not the case. And presently I think I do not have the skills to create a whole new control as you describe, so looks like my programming expedition has come to an end. Thanks.