# Add an image to Visual studio text view tab

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

Does anyone know how to add a image similar to Productivity Power Tools text view tab when there is an error in the file.

[image: Productivity Power Tools example]


Couldn't find any reading related to adding image to file tab in MSDN or tech blogs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The section you'd like to customize is the tab in the Document Well. There isn't any way to achieve this as far as I know since there isn't any SDK to access Document Well for now. Similar question here: [How do I programmatically access the Document Well in Visual Studio..?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42518405/how-do-i-programmatically-access-the-document-well-in-visual-studio)